# Klarna in flutter

Tags: java, kotlin, dart, klarna

I am trying to implement a Klarna payment solution in flutter for an app. The problem is that I don't know how to run Kotlin or Java code in flutter. Is it feasible or do I have to find another solution?

Kotlin code:

```
val paymentView: KlarnaPaymentView = findViewById(R.id.paymentView)
paymentView.category = KlarnaPaymentCategory.PAY_LATER 
paymentView.registerPaymentViewCallback(callback)
```

Java code:

```
final KlarnaPaymentView paymentView = findViewById(R.id.paymentView);
paymentView.setCategory(KlarnaPaymentCategory.PAY_LATER);
paymentView.registerPaymentViewCallback(callback);
```

Comment: I am also intrested in this. Did you found any solution?

Comment: Yes, for android. But it was quite a hurdle and sadly no support from Klarna. I am not happy with the solution either.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are platform channels. Basically, you write native platform-specific methods and invoke them through a platform channel in your Dart code.

Learn how to do so here : [Writing custom platform-specific code](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)

**EDIT :** the package [mollie](https://pub.dev/packages/mollie) seems to include the Klarna Sofort payment method. That may fit your needs.